# Minecraft - Multiple PlotMe Worlds On One Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I'm wondering if it would be possible to have two (or more) plotme worlds on one server?

So far my permissions allow users to do /p auto in any world. This teleports them to the one and only plotme world.

The way I think might work would be editing the permissions so only users in one of the plotme worlds can claim a plot. This would then hopefully make it so that you can claim a plot in *World 1* and another in *World 2* - hopefully all using the one plugin.

Any help would be of great appreciation!

A couple of notes:

- I'm running Spigot 1.8
- I've got other worlds as well (if it mattered...) ie. *survival, spawn world etc.*

Answer (score -1):

### Answer

Yes you can have multiple world on one server. But you needed a plugin.

### What plugin then?

It depends on what you need! There is a lot of plugin that serves this (Ex:Multiverse). Since it depends, I can't help you with installing and permission noding. There is a lot of tutorial out there.

Comment: I've already got multiverse, in fact, that's what I used to create the first plotme world... Thanks though! Hope you see what I mean now, I didn't explain it thoroughly in the first post.

Comment: I think you can generate 2 PlotMe world in the world config but I'm not sure since I've not tested it. Just try editing the config and search for tutorial. That's only what I can help for now.

Comment: @Chistopher_Angelo Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow :D